# Returning *this with non-reference return type changes value in calling object

Tags: c++

I am attempting to implement a linked list class in c++ to better understand them but I have run into something I find weird. I debugged with Visual Studio to see the results described below.

My problem was that before my function appendNode returned *this with a non-reference return type:

```
list<T> list<T>::appendNode(T value) {}
```

the values in the calling object's head node were set to the correct values, but after the function returned, the values in the calling object's head node had garbage, or at least definitely not what I set them as. My head->node pointer is always set to 0xddddddd and my program crashes on the second call to appendNode.

My solution is to make it return a reference:

```
list<T> &list<T>::appendNode(T value) {}
```

the solution works, all values are correct and the program runs fine.

The address of liOne isn't getting changed after each iteration so it still has the same head value, and head is still pointing to the same node. I've checked everything in the debugger.

My question is, why are the values in the calling object's head member being set to garbage with a non-reference return type?

My code with the non-reference return type:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class list
{
private:
    class ListNode
    {
    public:
        T value;
        ListNode * node;
    };
    ListNode * head;
public:
    list();
    list(T value);
    ~list();
    list<T> appendNode(T value);
    list<T> insertNode(T value);
    list<T> deleteNode(T value);
    void displayList() const;
};

/*
    Constructor list() creates an empty list with the head pointed to null
 */
template <class T>
list<T>::list()
{
    head = nullptr;
}

/*
    Constructor list(T value) creates a list and creates the first node with
        the value value.
    Parameters:
        T value : the value of the first node created is initialized with
 */
template <class T>
list<T>::list(T value)
{
    head = new ListNode();
    head->value = value;
    head->node = nullptr;
}

/*
    appendNode adds a new node to the end of the list
    Parameters:
        T value - the value to place in the new node
    Return:
        returns this for chain calling
 */
template <class T>
list<T> list<T>::appendNode(T value)
{
    ListNode * newNode = new ListNode();
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->node = nullptr;

    ListNode * nextNode = nullptr;

    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        nextNode = head;
        while (nextNode->node)
        {
            nextNode = nextNode->node;
        }
        nextNode->node = newNode;
    }

    return *this;
}

/*
    displayList displays the list contents
 */
template <class T>
void list<T>::displayList() const
{
    ListNode * currNode = head;

    while (currNode)
    {
        std::cout << currNode->value << " ";
        currNode = currNode->node;
    }
}

template <class T>
list<T>::~list()
{
    ListNode * currNode = head;
    ListNode * nextNode = nullptr;

    while (currNode)
    {
        nextNode = currNode->node;

        delete currNode;

        currNode = nextNode;
    }
}

#endif
```

Driver:

```
    #include <iostream>

#include "list.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    list<int> liOne;
    list<int> liTwo(0);

    liOne.appendNode(3);
    liOne.appendNode(4);

    liTwo.appendNode(1);
    liTwo.appendNode(2);

    liOne.displayList();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    liTwo.displayList();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press <ENTER> to exit...";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rule of 3/5/0... You have a destructor, but no copy constructor, no copy assignment.

Comment: [*What is the Rule of Three?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)